# Strategy Exit for Inside days

Tags: pine-script

My Strategy gets posted, but my strategy exit is not being displayed on the chart. Also, my strategy tester is showing all `0` values on all but Buy and Hold.

I've already tried using parentheses. The strategy exit factors are fairly similar to the strategy entry. Both entry and exit have the same values (Open and close)

```
Inside_days = (high < high[1] and low > low[1])

long = low < low[1]

short = high > high[1]

strategy.entry("GO LONG", strategy.long, when = Inside_days)

strategy.entry("GO SHORT", strategy.short, when = Inside_days)

strategy.close("OFF LONG", when = long and Inside_days)

strategy.close("OFF SHORT", when = short and Inside_days)
```

I expect the chart to be posted with proper values on the strategy tester and the strategy and exit signals placed on the correct places.

What I'm getting as of right now is my strategy entry signals are showing up, but my strategy close signals are absent.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the **same order id** that you want to close in `strategy.close()` calls.

Here is an example from the Pine Script Reference Manual:

```
strategy("closeEntry Demo", overlay=false)
strategy.entry("buy", true, when = open > close)
strategy.close("buy", when = open < close)
plot(strategy.position_size)
```